# How to display and remove an Image in kivy?

Tags: python, image, kivy

I've been searching for an answer for two hours now. What I am trying to accomplish in kivy is this:

```
import time
clear      = "\033[2J\033[1;1f"

print("""
################################
##this should display an image##
################################""")
time.sleep(1)
print(clear)
print("""
#####################################
##this should display another image##
#####################################""")
```

It is the beginning of a program I already got ready, but not as a real Desktop Application as if it would be with kivy.

The **program begins with showing an image, pausing for a second, then not showing an image before initiating the main menu** with buttons and so on (not important).

This is what I have so far (not working) :

```
class Intro(FloatLayout):
    connection   = Image(source='connection.png')
    noconnection = Image(source='noconnection.png')
    checkloop = True
    def check_connection(self, dt):
           url='http://www.google.com/'
           timeout=5
           connected.stop()
           noconnection.stop()
           try:
               server     = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
               _ = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
               connected.play()
               self.add_widget(self.connection)
               Clock.schedule_once(self.remove_widget(self.connection), 1)
               checkloop = False
           except requests.ConnectionError:
               noconnection.play()
               self.add_widget(self.noconnection)
               self.remove_widget(self.noconnection)
               txtinput = TextInput(text='ConnectionError. Enter to try again...')
           except smtplib.SMTPConnectError:
               noconnection.play()
               img = Image(source='noconnection.png')
               self.add_widget(self.noconnection)
               self.remove_widget(self.noconnection)
               txtinput = TextInput(text='SMTPConnectError. Enter to try again...')

class I41(App):
    def build(self):
        self.icon = 'riseicon.png'
        self.title = '41'
        intro      = Intro()
        Clock.schedule_once(intro.check_connection)
        print("DONE")
```

What am I doing wrong still?

I hope you guys can help me! First questions asked on stackoverflow!

Comment: You can't use time.sleep(1) with Kivy because it is blocking and will cause the app to hang. You have to set a timer using kivy.clock. Have a look at this https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html.

Comment: You _can_ use time.sleep with Kivy, it just doesn't do what you want and using Clock.schedule_once is an appropriate solution.

Comment: Also your `return`s don't make sense - the function returns a values as soon as it hits the first one, any later ones will never be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `check_connection()` method you have many `return` statements. Note that the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement). says:

> return leaves the current function

So anything after a return is encountered will not be executed, and any other code in the method will be stopped (like a `while` loop).

A fix is to call the code that you want executed after `return` using a call to `Clock.schedle_once()` .

Here is a simple example of how to do that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class MyFloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    img = Image(source='connection.png')
    checkloop = True

    def showImage(self, dt):
        self.add_widget(self.img)

        # other code here, like connecting to Google

        if self.checkloop:
            # continue loop
            Clock.schedule_once(self.deleteImage, 1)

    def deleteImage(self, dt):
        self.remove_widget(self.img)
        if self.checkloop:
            # continue loop
            Clock.schedule_once(self.showImage, 1)


class I41(App):
    def build(self):
        self.icon = 'riseicon.png'
        self.title = '41'
        root = MyFloatLayout()

        # start image loop
        Clock.schedule_once(root.showImage)

        return root

I41().run()
```

The loop is stopped by setting `checkloop` to `False` in `MyFloatLayout`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I edited my code, but it does not work still... What am I still doing wrong? There are no errors coming up, just not the pictures showing nor the sound playing...

Comment: You are still using `time.sleep()` . When you run a method on the main thread, as your `check_connection()` is, The GUI cannot update until that method completes. The `check_connection()` method adds a widget to the GUI, sleeps for 2 seconds, removes that widget, then returns. After the return, the App regains access to the main thread and updates the GUI, which at that time does not have a `connection` widget. Have a closer look at my answer, where delays are accomplished using `Clock.schedule_once()`.

Comment: I exchanged time.sleep for Clock.schedule_once ... still nothing happens... What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: In your `Clock.schedule_once` you use `self.remove_widget(self.connection)`. That code removes the `connection` widget immediately, then schedules a call to the return of that method (which is `None`). Try using `Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.remove_widget, self.connection), 1)`, which schedule a call to `self.remove_widget` with the argument `self.connection`.

Comment: Got it! Works! Thanks!